# Insertar registros desde excel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy leyendo datos dede un excel e insertandolos en una tablea temporal de una base de datos mysql, ese proceso lo hago sin problemas, pero lo que neceito hacer ahora es que, una vez que ya tengo los datos en la tabla temporal, hacer una consulta a la misma tabla de todos los registros del campo llamado "tempdth_sal_id" y a medida que me vaya entregando resultados vaya consultado por ese mismo campo a otra tabla y me traiga los datos correspondientes,al intentarlo   me muestra esete error: "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string",
este es mi codigo:

```
 $sale1=db::select("SELECT tempdth_sal_id FROM $nombreTablaTemp");
                          
               
                for($x=0;$x<$sale1;$x++)
                    {
                        $nombresal=$sale1[$x]; 

                        $idsale=Sale::where('sal_nombre',$nombresal)->get();

                    };
```

les agradecería si me pueden ayudar con esto por favor.

Comment: Probá reemplazar el `for` por un `foreach ($sale1 as $sale) { dd($sale); }` y fijate que estás trayendo.

Comment: Probablemente en `$sale1[$x]` tengas un objeto en vez de un string. Prueba acceder a la propiedad del objeto que te interesa

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @azeós y @porloscerrosΨ, con sus comentarios pude resolverlo, esta fue mi solución:

```php
$sale1=DB::table($nombreTablaTemp)->select('tempdth_sal_id')->get();
$array = json_decode($sale1, true);
$cuenta=$sale1->count();

for($x=0;$x<$cuenta;$x++)
{
    $codsale=$array[$x]['tempdth_sal_id'];

    $idsale=Sale::where('sal_nombre',$codsale)->first();
    $nuevoid=$idsale->sal_id;

    DB::table($nombreTablaTemp)->where('tempdth_sal_id', $codsale)->update(['tempdth_sal_id'=>$nuevoid]);
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo funciona este código. Para ti ha de ser una obviedad, pero otros usuarios con el mismo inconveniente verán tu respuesta y probablemente no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer]. Por último, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.